# How do I retrieve formatted input mapped in Excel Cell in Flex in Xcelsius tool

Tags: excel, xcelsius, flex2

I have a formatted input excel value eg.$650.How can I retrieve this value in Property Sheet Flex Code in Flex ?Is there any function name in Interfaces in Xcelsius SDK function names?If so please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as the relavant function is not available in existing Xcelsius SDK.